# What can I cure at 15c and 50% humidity?

Tags: meat, temperature, curing

I have a basement that stays at a pretty regular 15c and 50% humidity. I dont want to set up a chamber for curing, Id rather just use the conditions I have.

The issue is I cant seem to find products that fit these environments. Is there anything? Whole muscle needs less humidity and more warmth whilst sausage needs more humidity.

Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty close to the temperature and humidity of the closet where I store wine and hang salumi to cure.  I've had the most success with pancetta, lomo, and brasola. I've had some successes and some failures with dried sausages and salami, usually related to undesirable mold that I didn't catch in time.  I probably wouldn't hang an entire pork leg, in an effort to make something like a prosciutto.  Generally, because of the cost and labor involved, I would want the conditions to be more precise and less variable.  In my wine closet, the temp and humidity does change.  However, for the smaller items I am playing with, and given the time necessary, the conditions are just fine.  It sounds like a reasonable place to experiment.  One final note, be sure your space is insect and rodent-free.  That could be a potential issue.

Comment: Yes this seems to make sense, you think its best to go with whole muscle as its easier and needs less precision?

Comment: @Camboselecta, that has been my experience...I have done a whole pork belly, not rolled, as pancetta.  That is probably the largest cut I have cured.  Usually, though, I am doing smaller pieces...1/2 belly...or a 2 lb tenderloin (lomo) or eye of round (for bresola).  The need for more precision would be if I had to hang something for many months, as I don't have temp and humidity control...but neither did folks 100 years ago, so I could certainly work.